# Calculate max flow efficiently using Ford Fulkerson after removing edge from the flow

Tags: algorithm, ford-fulkerson

Suppose that a maximum ﬂow for G has been computed using Ford-Fulkerson, but an edge is now removed from E. how the maximum ﬂow can be efﬁciently updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the edge `e` you removed crosses the cut, then the maximum flow is equal to `|f| − c(e)`, where `|f|` is the previously computed maximum flow and `c(e)` is the capacity of the removed edge.

You can find detailed explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809660/max-flow-minimum-cut-after-removing-an-edge).